# Lifter lms not activating

Tags: wordpress

I accidentally deleted ' wp_actionscheduler_actions' table from wordpress database.
Now if I tries to install and activate Lifter LMS plugin.

It throws error ' wp_actionscheduler_actions does not exist' .

I tried recreating the wp_actionscheduler_actions table looking at another fresh installation of lifter lms.
Still not working.
How to solve this without deleting anymore database tables?

Comment: You should *never* go near the database of any system if you are not *100% sure* what you’re doing, and even then you always take a backup first... you did take a backup I presume? If so, you’ll need to recreate the database from it. If you didn’t, I don’t know if it’s even possible to recover, because there was presumably data in there that’s now gone forever.

Comment: Yes, I have back up but not accessible for at least few days. I was looking for some other ideas to recover by then.

Comment: Once the data is deleted, it’s gone forever.  I’m not familiar with that plugin, but unless you know exactly what data was in the table before it was deleted and what references the other tables had to it, then I don’t see how you can recover I’m afraid. If you have to wait a few days for the backup, I presume it’s part of a general scheduled backup. For future reference, you can take your own SQL dump from the database yourself -*always* do this before you attempt to make the slightest change in the database (or better yet, stay away from the database entirely)

Comment: Completely removed the plugin and reinstall after recovering entire database. It is working now.